# Passing strings with spaces to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-scripting

Ultimately, I want to be able to call my PS script from VBA (Excel), but the easiest way to do that seems to be with system batch commands - so I'm testing my script with a BAT file.

The script returns a text file with the contents of a webpage, sans HTML tags. It works fine called alone with default parameters; it worked fine with no spaces in the output path parameter, but I've had no luck using a path that includes a space.

PS1 script, boiled down:

```
param ( [string]$outputPathName="" )
$outputPathName | Out-File "D:\Documents\Google Drive\out.txt"
```

BAT file to test it:

```
powershell.exe '"D:\Documents\Google Drive\GetWebPage.ps1"' -outputPathName '"D:\Documents\Google Drive\out.txt"'
```

I get the error message "Unexpected token '-outputPathName' in expression or statement." (I also get a similar error for the argument, but if the parameter name were recognized I might be able to get past this.)

How can I pass a named argument in from BAT script file to PS1 script file (with spaces in the path and argument)?

Comment: Use PowerShell's `-File` parameter and quote the filename. (Run `powershell /?` for more information.)

Comment: OK, thanks for that! That led me to the correct usage:

`powershell.exe -file "D:\Documents\Google Drive\GetWebPage.ps1" -outputPathName "D:\Documents\Google Drive\out.txt"`